# Why Iterator.next() throws ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, iterator, while-loop

Strangly enough, this small piece of code throws the above mentioned Exception.
Also, looking at code posted around the web this seems to be correct:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class IteratorTest {

    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Iterator i = arr.iterator();

    public void show() {
        arr.add(2);
        arr.add(5);
        arr.add(9);

        while(i.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(i.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This call:

```
Iterator i=arr.iterator();
```

should be after you've done all the writes into your ArrayList.

So in your code do this just before you start iterating like this:

```
Iterator i=arr.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thx anbhava, so basically Iterator will not update itself if changes to the Iterable are performed. i did not know this thx

Comment: I think a for loop is better than while loop in that you're limiting he scope of the iterator variable `i`.

Answer (score 7):

It's because you've modified the backing list between getting the Iterator via `iterator()` and calling `next()`.

The typical usage of an Iterator is:

```
for (Iterator<Integer> iter=arr.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Integer element = iter.next();
}
```

Or better yet, use the new for-each loop:

```
for (Integer element: arr) {
}
```

Make sure to to perform additions to the Collection outside of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You are defining the `Iterator` upon instantiation of your object, `IteratorTest`. You then add some data to the `ArrayList`, `arr`.

You have now modified your list, and thus the `Iterator`'s state is invalid.

You cannot use the `Iterator` and change the `ArrayList` without using the `Iterator` to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 4 is technically correct, but not because a `for(;;)` or "for each" loop is used instead of a `while()` loop.  It simply a matter of the Iterator's declared scope within the Class rather than the method. First, let's look at the behavior of the two methods `hasNext()` and `next()`:

The `hasNext()` method simply queries an internal cursor (index); `next()` actually advances the cursor, therefore that is the "modification" that could raise the exception.  If you try to use an Iterator declared and assigned outside of the method in which `next()` is being used, the code will throw an exception on the first `next()`, regardless if it's a `for(;;)` or `while()`.

In Answer 4 and 8, the iterator is declared and consumed locally within the method.  It just so happens that since the `for(;;)` construct allows for a first time declaration and assignment of the iterator before the loop executes (which makes the iterator scoped to the `for(;;)` and implicitly within the method, making it "safe"). I agree that the `for(;;)` idiom is cleaner syntactically and fences scope at the lowest level of execution, completely within the `for(;;)` loop.

Answer 8 is correct, because the Iterator is assigned and used locally inside the method.

But, just for sake of the discussion, the following method using a `while()` statement is syntactically correct, "safe" and non-modifying from a scope and reference perspective:

somewhere in the Class definition
...

```
ArrayList<String> messageList;
```

somewhere in the class constructor

```
messageList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

add a method...

```
public printMessages ( )
{

  Iterator<String> messageIterator = messageList.iterator();

  while (messageIterator.hasNext())
     {
     System.out.println(messageIterator.next());
     }

  System.out.flush();

}
```